# Why C++ Program Give me address instead value in MxN Array Col-Wise Sum but give me value in NxN Array?

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, return-value, col

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
   int matrix_A[10][10],row, col,csum=0;

   //Getting the rows from user and storing in row
   cout<<"--------------------------"<<endl;
   cout<<"|Enter The Number Of Rows|"<<"\n";
   cout<<"--------------------------"<<endl;
   cin>>row;
   //Getting the columns from user and storing in col
   cout<<"-----------------------------"<<endl;
   cout<<"|Enter The Number Of Columns|"<<"\n";
   cout<<"-----------------------------"<<endl;
   cin>>col;

   /* Asking the user to input the elements of matrix
    * and storing them in the matrix array
    */
   cout<<"---------------------------------------"<<endl;
   cout<<"|Enter The Elements Of The Matrix A Is|"<<endl;
   cout<<"---------------------------------------"<<"\n";
   for(int i =0;i<row;i++) {
     for(int j=0;j<col;j++) {
       cin>>matrix_A[i][j];
     }
   }

// Display column-wise sum of matrix of size m x n
    cout<<"----------------------------------------"<<"\n";
    cout<<"|The Column-Wise Sum Of The Matrix A Is|"<<"\n";
    cout<<"----------------------------------------"<<"\n";
        for(int i=0;i<row;i++)
        {
            csum =0;
            for(int j=0;j<col;j++){
                csum = csum + matrix_A[j][i];
            }
        cout<<csum<<"\t";

}
return 0;
}
```

#### This code give me the Value of col-wise sum only when i enter a square matrix nxn but when enter mxn matrix it give me the address.

### 1.What is the reason ?

### 2.How to make the program give value in mxn matrix ?

Comment: Why do you think it gives you an address? (Look at your indexing more carefully.)

Answer (score 0):

> This code give me the Value of col-wise sum only when i enter a square matrix nxn but when enter mxn matrix it give me the address.

Okay let's see why

Let `row` = 3 and `col` = 2

and your matrix be

```
[ 
  [1,2],
  [3,4],
  [6,7]
]
```

Now in your loop

```
for(int i=0;i<row;i++)
        {
            csum =0;
            for(int j=0;j<col;j++){
                csum = csum + matrix_A[j][i];
            }
        cout<<csum<<"\t";
```

`i` will be 0,1,2

`j` will be 0,1

now when

`csum = csum + matrix_A[j][i];`

happens. During the loop, this will also occur :

`csum = csum + matrix_A[0][2];`

and `matrix_A[0][2]` is not defined.

Comment: thank u for your explain,you help me to figure out the solution,if we transpose the matrix before get csum the problem will solve.

Answer (score 0):

you can use as follows.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
   int matrix_A[10][10],row, col, csum=0, rsum = 0;

   //Getting the rows from user and storing in row
   cout<<"--------------------------"<<endl;
   cout<<"|Enter The Number Of Rows|"<<"\n";
   cout<<"--------------------------"<<endl;
   cin>>row;
   //Getting the columns from user and storing in col
   cout<<"-----------------------------"<<endl;
   cout<<"|Enter The Number Of Columns|"<<"\n";
   cout<<"-----------------------------"<<endl;
   cin>>col;

   /* Asking the user to input the elements of matrix
    * and storing them in the matrix array
    */
   cout<<"---------------------------------------"<<endl;
   cout<<"|Enter The Elements Of The Matrix A Is|"<<endl;
   cout<<"---------------------------------------"<<"\n";
   for(int i =0;i<row;i++) {
     for(int j=0;j<col;j++) {
       cin>>matrix_A[i][j];
     }
   }

// Display column-wise sum of matrix of size m x n
    cout<<"----------------------------------------"<<"\n";
    cout<<"|The Column-Wise Sum Of The Matrix A Is|"<<"\n";
    cout<<"----------------------------------------"<<"\n";
        for(int i=0;i<col;i++)
        {
            csum =0;
            for(int j=0; j<row;j++){
                csum += matrix_A[j][i];
            }
        cout<<csum<<"\t";

        }
// Display row-wise sum of matrix of size m x n
    cout<<"----------------------------------------"<<"\n";
    cout<<"|The Row-Wise Sum Of The Matrix A Is|"<<"\n";
    cout<<"----------------------------------------"<<"\n";
        for(int i=0;i<row;i++)
        {
            rsum =0;
            for(int j=0; j<col;j++){
                rsum += matrix_A[i][j];
            }
        cout<<rsum<<endl;

        }
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### The solution is transpose the matrix before starting columns summtion

```
// Display column-wise
    cout<<"----------------------------------------"<<"\n";
    cout<<"|The Column-Wise Sum Of The Matrix A Is|"<<"\n";
    cout<<"----------------------------------------"<<"\n";
// Create transpose of matrix A of size n x m to get column-wise sum like row-wise sum
  for(int i=0;i<row;i++) {
    for(int j=0;j<col;j++) {
      matrix_B[j][i] = matrix_A[i][j];
    }
  }
// Display column-wise sum of matrix of size m x n
  for(int i=0;i<col;i++) {
        csum =0;
    for(int j=0;j<row;j++) {
      cout<<matrix_B[i][j]<<"\t";
    csum = csum + matrix_B[i][j];
      /* This is just to format the output
       * so you can see the matrix format
       * in the output transpose matrix.
       */
      if(j==row-1)
        cout<<"|  "<<csum;
    }
    cout<<"\n\n";
  }
```